# Is it possible to customise Android PopupMenu?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-menu

Is it possible to customise PopupMenu layout ? I just need with rounded corners, is it possible to customise with the stock one ?

Comment: Better to use  popupwindow https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Comment: Easy solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48146479/986739

Answer (score 0):

For custom layouts don't use PopupMenu, alternate option is a [PopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)

```
  PopupWindow popupwindow_obj = popupDisplay();
  popupwindow_obj.showAsDropDown(clickbtn, -40, 18); // where u want show on view click event popupwindow.showAsDropDown(view, x, y);

public PopupWindow popupDisplay() { 

    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(this);

    // inflate your layout or dynamically add view
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_popupwindow_layout, null);


    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupWindow.setContentView(view);

    return popupWindow;
}
```

And create this `my_popupwindow_layout.xml` file in the `res/layout` folder, which is used to inflate the custom layout for the popupWindow.

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Window test" />
</LinearLayout>
```